# When trying to render code it is saying "Chart" is undefined but it is in the jQuery. Did I not call the jQuery correctly?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a pie chart to render from jQuery but I am not sure I am calling it correctly. My CSS renders, and it works on codepen but in chrome it is saying "Chart" is undefined, though it is defined in the jQuery. That leads me to believe I am not calling the external jQuery properly.

```
    jQuery(function(){
    require(['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.js'])
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [{
            data: [42, 8, 50],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#ed6a47",
                "#faae53",
                "#ffd5a3",
            ],

            borderWidth: 0
            }]
        },
        options: {
            cutoutPercentage: 50,
            responsive: false,

        }
        });
      });  
    ]]></xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call jquery before script with script tag.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

JQuery functions use `$` to start it. So instead of `jQuery(function()`, it should actually be `$(function()`.

Comment: Not necessarily,not if you are using [`noConflict`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for example. Despite that both `$` and `jQuery` are valid

Comment: @empiric well, he/she doesn't show the use of `noConflict`.

Comment: That was an example and doesn't matter, even without `noConflict` you can use jQuery functions with `$` and `jQuery` as a prefix